# Upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 hosts to support Shibboleth SP 3

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, shibboleth

I've inherited a few Ubuntu 14.04 hosts which are configured with Shibboleth auth through Apache. They run rails/apache. The installed packages(1) on these hosts is `libapache2-mod-shib2` along with a few files(2) under `/etc/shibboleth` which look new/modified/added.

Trying to upgrade these hosts to 16.04 but one of our devs mentioned shibboleth 2 is deprecated. I pulled up a [page on switch.ch](https://www.switch.ch/aai/guides/sp/installation/?os=ubuntu) which only shows a SWITCH repo of SP3 for 18.04 (radio button under Introduction) but then about half-way down the page (under Add Repository) there are directions for adding a 16.04 repo. Is this a typo? I'd rather just upgrade to SP3 and not have to screw around with installing 18.04 if possible.

(1)

```
libapache2-mod-shib2
liblog4shib1v5:amd64
libshibsp-plugins:amd64
libshibsp7:amd64
shibboleth-sp2-common
shibboleth-sp2-utils
```

(2)

```
sp-key.pem
sp-cert.pem
shibboleth2.xml
```